# How can I debug a non-working motherboard?

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

I have a (3 year old) Gigabyte GA-Z77X-D3H that doesn't turn on anymore when pressing the power button.

The button is plugged properly and shorts the pins when pressed.

I changed the power supply unit but was able to confirm that this is not the problem by shorting pins 15 and 16 on the ATX-Power connector which turns on the power to the mainboard, starting the fans, illuminating the leds.

Problem is that even this doesn't start the mainboard (it doesn't start booting while the power supply is forced on)

How can I debug the mainbord, eventually finding the error?

Comment: so if you have the bare minimum plugged in (one memory stick, power, and a video card / onboard?

Comment: @EricF Yes. The mainboard is not reacting on power or reset button.

Comment: So if you short the two pins (placing something metal to connect them like a screwdriver or something) does it boot up and display properly?

Comment: @EricF Nope. I dont get anything on the screen. Neither VGA, nor HDMI output

Comment: do you have a computer speaker plugged in? The ones that look like magnets? If so can you tell me the beep code?

Comment: @EricF Sorry, I dont have one at hand. Do I have any other ways of checking the mainboard? Measuring some specific voltages? Scoping any frequency? :D

Comment: Had one do this just yesterday. CMOS battery was dead. As soon as it was replaced, it came back to life.

Comment: @CharlieRB I've placed a new CR2032 CMOS battery, but it unfortunately didn't help

Comment: Bummer. From everything you have described and tried, I am inclined to think this is a dead motherboard.

Comment: Make sure the "clear CMOS" jumper isn't in the clear position.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to pick up one of those computer speakers before declaring the thing dead. It will provide you a beep code and then you can figure out what is truly wrong